# Duvida sobre validação para a execução do modal

Tags: c#

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de controle e acabei travando em uma parte, tenho duas classes, a `equipamento` e a `area`, onde uma área pode ter um ou muitos equipamentos e um equipamento pertence a uma unica área...

Estou conseguindo fazer o `crud` do equipamento certinho, porém o da área estou tendo dificuldades, pois como o equipamento tem a chave estrangeira da área, não consigo excluir uma determinada área se algum equipamento estiver cadastrado nela.

Logo para resolver este problema coloquei um modal para quando o usuário for excluir uma área com equipamento cadastrado, avise-o que deve primeiro editar a área do equipamento. Caso não houver nenhum equipamento cadastrado, poderá confirmar a exclusão!

Só que estou com duvida do que colocar como retorno no meu `controller`, para depois passar para a `View` e abrir o modal.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

meu repositório:

```
//Este método verifica se há algum equipamento cadastrado na área
        public bool BuscarEquipamentoArea(string area)
        {
            strQuery = "select areArea from tblArea inner join tblEquipamento on areArea = equArea where areArea = @equipamento";
            return db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(strQuery, new SqlParameter("equipamento", area)).FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false;
        }
```

minha `AreaController`:

```
 public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            tblArea tblArea = db.tblArea.Find(id);
            if (tblArea == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            AreaRepositorio areaRepo = new AreaRepositorio(db);
            if (areaRepo.BuscarEquipamentoArea(id) == true)
            {
                //não sei que tipo de retorno coloco aqui para avisar a view que tem q exibir o Modal
            }

            return View(tblArea);
        }

        // POST: Area/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {

                tblArea tblArea = db.tblArea.Find(id);
                db.tblArea.Remove(tblArea);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Minha View:

```
<td class="am">
      @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.areArea }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Details", new { id = item.areArea }) |
  @*(caso exista algum equipamento cadastrado nessa área, terá que ser igual a true)*@
      @if(algumaCoisaAqui== true){
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#btnDeletar" })
      }
      else{
           @Html.ActionLink("Excluir", "Delete", new { id = item.areArea })
      }
</td>
```

Meu modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="btnDeletar" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Alerta!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Exclua ou Edite primeiro os Equipamentos cadastrados nesta área!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="~/" class="btn btn-default">Ir para Equipamentos</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou querendo realizar essa verificação na index, pois antes do usuário confirmar a exclusão eu já quero informar se pode ou não com o modal.

alguem poderia me ajudar, a fazer isso? Não sei o que colocar nos campos comentados

Comment: Só pelo título eu já não entendi a sua pergunta... por que a `Controller` deveria saber qualquer coisa que se passa na `View`?

Comment: Então eu não sei como fazer a validação direito, tipo o que eu colocaria no if do controller caso exista um equipamento cadastrado? Como avisaria a View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
if(validacao)
{
      ... // O que tem que ser feito caso validação esteja certa.
      return RedirectToAction("VIEW_VALIDACAO_OK");
}
else 
{
      ViewBag.Erro = "MENSAGEM PARA A VIEW";
      return View("VIEW_QUE_ESTA",objeto)  
}
```

```html
@{
    var varViewBag = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Erro);
}


@if(varViewBag != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning"> @varViewBag </div>
}
```